# issue with maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, twilio

Trying to execute [twilio Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) api fails as follows:

```
18:17:35.270 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
18:17:35.296 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
18:17:35.297 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Reopening the direct connection.
18:17:35.297 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.twilio.sdk.AppEngineClientConnection.flush(AppEngineClientConnection.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:410)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:581)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at ws.SmsSender.main(SmsSender.java:34)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:98)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:37)
    ... 16 more
18:17:35.334 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Closing the connection.
```

I think it has something to do with a dependency issue in Maven. Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.wat</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ws</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>foursquareapijava</id>
            <name>Foursquare V2 API for Java Repository</name>
            <url>http://foursquare-api-java.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.vz.mongodb.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-jackson-mapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
           <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
           <version>3.4.5</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fi.foyt</groupId>
            <artifactId>foursquare-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-integration</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>ws.WSService</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here's the output from mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

```
Last login: Tue Jun 24 18:09:15 on ttys002
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ws 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ws ---
[INFO] com.wat:ws:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.yammer.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.17.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.4)
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-servlet:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.4)
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-jetty:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.8.v20121106:compile - omitted for conflict with 8.1.10.v20130312)
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-logback:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.10)
[INFO] |  |  \- (ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.10)
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-jersey:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.15:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.17.1)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.1)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.4)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.4)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 14.0.1)
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.4)
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.10.v20130312:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.1)
[INFO] +- com.yammer.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.yammer.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:0.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.vz.mongodb.jackson:mongo-jackson-mapper:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.7.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.12.0-rc2)
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.3:compile (version managed from 1.9.5)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.undercouch:bson4jackson:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9.3)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.3:compile - version managed from 1.7.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.3:compile - version managed from 1.7.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.12.0-rc2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.4)
[INFO] |  \- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.2)
[INFO] +- fi.foyt:foursquare-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.901 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-06-24T18:41:27-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
$
```

And the code being executed:

```
package ws;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.CallFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.*;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.AccountList;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.AvailablePhoneNumberList;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.ParticipantList;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.*;



public class SmsSender {

  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "<HIDDEN>";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "<HIDDEN>";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();

    // Send an sms (using the new messages endpoint)
    MessageFactory messageFactory = mainAccount.getMessageFactory();
    List<NameValuePair> messageParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+HIDDEN")); // Replace with a valid phone number
    messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+HIDDEN")); // Replace with a valid phone
    // number in your account
    messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "This is a test message!"));
    messageFactory.create(messageParams);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From twilio:

> Hi Matthew,
>
> Thanks for checking with us.
>
> It looks like "foursquare-api" is bringing in the
>   "appengine-api-1.0-sdk" dependency.
>
> ```
> [INFO] +- fi.foyt:foursquare-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
> [INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
> [INFO] |  \- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.6.5:compile
> ```
>
> You can try excluding this dependency, however I expect it will
>   probably break the "foursquare-api" library.
>
> "twilio-java" does not have a hard dependency on App Engine for this
>   reason.
>
> Please let us know if you have any other questions.
>
> Alex Chan Twilio Customer Support www.twilio.com

Updated pom.xml as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fi.foyt</groupId>
        <artifactId>foursquare-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```